# VB.net - TextBox updated via code is not committed with DataTable.AcceptChanges

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have what I believe to be a small oddity in my code.  I have a textbox (txtEmail) that get text added to it via code: `txtEmail.Text = "Text Here"`  If I don't tab through the text box before I try to save the record, the text is lost when executing the DataTable.AcceptChanges.

I have tested this by:

1. Not tabbing through the textboxes - Text gets lost
2. Tabbing through the textboxes- Text is committed
3. "Selecting" the textbox via code, then selecting another textbox - Text is commited

Is there something I am missing?  Is there any way I can commit the text without selecting or tabbing through the textboxes?

For reference, the textboxes are bound to a binding source, who's DataSource is a DataTable.

Some snippets of code to maybe help...

Filling DA and DT, setting BS:

```
Using SQLcmd As New SqlCommand With {
    .Connection = Vars.sqlConn,
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Database].[Table]"}
    da_Users.SelectCommand = SQLcmd
    Dim sqlCB As New SqlCommandBuilder(da_Users)
    AddHandler da_Users.RowUpdated, AddressOf OnRowUpdated

    da_Users.Fill(dt_Users)
    dt_Users.Columns("Active").DefaultValue = True
    dt_Users.Columns("Phone").DefaultValue = "6-1800, ()"

    bs_Users.DataSource = dt_Users
    bsnav_Users.BindingSource = bs_Users
End Using
```

Updating Email Textbox

```
Private Sub txtName_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtLastName.Leave, txtFirstName.Leave
    Try
        Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        tb.Text = StrConv(tb.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase)

        If Not txtFirstName.Text = "" And Not txtLastName.Text = "" Then
            Dim strFNames() = txtFirstName.Text.Trim.Split(New Char() {" "c})
            Dim strLNames() = txtLastName.Text.Trim.Split(New Char() {" "c})
            txtEmail.Text = strLNames(0) & "." & strFNames(0) & "@sample.com"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        CustExErrorMsg(Name, Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, GetExceptionInfo(ex))
    End Try
End Sub
```

Saving the record:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BNavSaveItem.Click
    Try
        If IsComplete() Then
            If blnNew Then If IsDuplicate() Then Exit Sub

            lblTSS.Text = "Saving..."
            lblTSS.BackColor = Color.IndianRed
            Application.DoEvents()
            
            'Added to commit text
            txtEmail.Select()
            txtFirstName.Select()

            Me.Validate()
            If blnNew Then dt_Users.AcceptChanges()
            bs_Users.EndEdit()
            da_Users.Update(dt_Users)
            
            lblTSS.Text = "Done"
            lblTSS.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        End If

    Catch SqlExceptionErr As SqlException
        CustSQLErrorMsg(Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, SqlExceptionErr.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        CustExErrorMsg(Name, Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, GetExceptionInfo(ex))
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you calling `AcceptChanges()` there? The DataAdapter does this on its own (when actually needed) **after** you have committed the changes to the database (calling `Update()`), to reset the state of all Rows.

Comment: @Jimi  You are correct, commenting that out did the trick.  Not really sure why I was calling `AcceptChanges` other than I may have had issues somewhere else?  Thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: `AcceptChanges()` should be called *manually*  the first time you load a DataTable. So all Rows have the `Unchanged` state. Otherwise, some changes may not be committed correctly.